# Uverse router with external fax modem

Tags: modem, phone

I have an external fax modem I want to install. Presently the phone line comes out  of the wall to the Uverse router. It plugs into what looks like a bank of phone jacks. THe modem I purchased plugs into the computer via a USB port. There is a phone jack in the modem. Where do I connect the fax modem to? the wall phone jack, or the bank of jacks on the rear of the Uverse router?

Answer (score 0):

From a friend: You must have VOIP. The phone line that goes from the wall to the Uverse gatyeway, disconnect the line at the gateway and put a splitter in. Re-connect the phone line, then connect the phone line from the fax modem. It worked. Thanks everyone for your help.